# Booked nights, per month in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, checkout, checkin

I have the data set (below a sample). Trying to get the number of nights, in each month

[image]

Comment: what about simple pivot table? or even simple `sum` row at the bottom?

Comment: Your data is pretty inconsistent. 6/15 -> 6/17 is 1 night (too few), 6/28 -> 6/29 is 1 night (correct) and 9/18 -> 9/24 is 6 nights (too many).

Comment: @Phylogenesis I agree with your first two assessments, but not with the third.

Comment: Use `NumOfDays = DateDiff("D", first_date, second_date)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that as the day of arrival goes with the first night, if someone arrived on 30th April and left on 1st May, that would count one night in April and zero nights in May. Using a slightly modified [overlap formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/calculate-date-overlap-in-days):

```
=IF(MIN(EDATE(C$1,1),$B2)<=MAX(C$1,$A2),"",MIN(EDATE(C$1,1),$B2)-MAX(C$1,$A2))
```

[image]

assuming that a formula solution is OK.